# Data quality - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a data quality project using Python and Pandas. I have an input dataframe where each column is categorical data, and I want to return a dataframe where each column consists of the top 10 most frequently occuring categories in that column in order, together with the name of said categories (ie a key value pair or a tuple with Categorical variable :  Count in each cell.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to build results DataFrame with a `MultiIndex` columns

```
np.random.seed(0)

#Create dataframe with random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.columns, ['index', 'count']), names= ['column', None])
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=range(1, 11))
```

and then, I see no other way than to loop over the columns

```
for column_name, column in df.items():
    top_10 = column.value_counts(normalize=False).iloc[:10]
    result[(column_name, 'index')] = top_10.index
    result[(column_name, 'count')] = top_10.values
```

> ```
> column     A           B           C           D      
>        index count index count index count index count
> 1         81     4    32     5     3     3    67     4
> 2         46     3    79     4     5     3     0     3
> 3         82     3    99     3    19     3    35     3
> 4         20     3    50     3    51     3    28     3
> 5         23     3    53     3    41     3    11     3
> 6         24     3    13     3    36     3    58     2
> 7         41     3    39     3    47     2    72     2
> 8         42     3    87     3    35     2    32     2
> 9         71     3    58     2    61     2    65     2
> 10         0     3    91     2    58     2    98     2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value-count pairs in dictionary format, as so:

```
df["column"].value_counts(False).to_dict()
```

And you can use this method *iteratively* to populate a dataframe, as so:

```
#Import dependencies
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Create dataframe with random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

#Create a 'result dataframe' 
resultDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(df.keys()))

#Append value-count pairs to new dataframe
for column in df.keys():
    _dict_ = df[column].value_counts(False).to_dict()
    for index, key in enumerate(_dict_):
        resultDf.loc[index, column] = [key,_dict_.get(key)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you happen to know of an efficient way of applying this to each column without using loops?

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately I don't. The above method will work, but I agree that doing this without loops would be preferred (more eloquent and faster).